# check if xml has root tag

Tags: php, regex, xml

I am trying to check if a piece of xml has a root tag.
As example

```
<xml>
  <test>test</test>
</xml>
```

Should be considered valid while

```
<test>test</test>
```

Should be considered invalid.

The first example should be processed as it is while the second example should be wrapped inside `<helper></helper>` tags.

What would be the best way to check this in PHP, i've been thinking of using a regular expression for it but I really don't know what the regular expression should be if we're also considering the tags can have attributes.

**Edit:** I am using simplexml_load_string to load the string in combination with a XML streamer, the problem is that the XML streamer shaves the xml file 1 tag at the time.

When I have a file like:

```
<xml>
  <name attr="test">Archcry</name>
  <test>
    <name>Archcry</name>
    <moreinfo>more info goes here</moreInfo>
  </test>
</xml>
```

I get pieces that look like:

```
<name attr="test">Archcry</name>
```

And:

```
<test>
  <name>Archcry</name>
  <moreinfo>more info goes here</moreInfo>
</test>
```

The second piece of code can be run through simplexml_load_string just fine.
But i'd like to add helper tags to the first piece because otherwise I don't get a nice xml object to work with

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: What do you use to read the XML? There are several PHP classes to do this.

Comment: @Camil Staps, I changed the main post with some more detailed examples of what I am trying to do.

Comment: @hwnd I think the answer marked as solution is better than using DOM because I already use simplexml for my script.

Comment: @SanderKoenders Yes in this case since you do use simplexml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out if an XML string has a root node you can use the simplexml class. 
For your purpose you can use the `children` method:

```
$string ="<test>test</test>";
// $string ="<xml><test>test</test></xml>";
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
if(count($xml->children() == 0) {
  echo "<helper>".$xml->asXML()."</helper>";
} else {
  // has root element;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm I thought I had tried this and I got some strange results indicating that attributes were also considered children. Yet when I try this piece of code it works just fine. (also with attributes). I'm going to look into this :D